# Problem in Increasing Label in Material-Ui in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I have successfully increased the Label in the TextField of my React app.
My problem is that when its on shrink, it just overlaps some line on its right.

[image: Click Here]

[Click Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-custom-textfield-composition-forked-m6j18?file=/src/Demo.js)

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiInputLabel-shrink": {
      fontSize: "24px"
    }
  }
}));

export default function CustomTextField({ InputLabelProps = {}, ...props }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <TextField {...props} className={classes.root} />;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to always use the DevTools when it comes to applying customizations. The size of the gap it determined by the `<legend>` element:

[image]

The element's font size has a font-size: 0.75em to account for the CSS transformation.

So you can simply apply the same font size to its parent:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiInputLabel-shrink, & fieldset": {
      fontSize: "24px"
    }
  }
}));

export default function CustomTextField({ InputLabelProps = {}, ...props }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <TextField {...props} className={classes.root} />;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-custom-textfield-composition-forked-g5co7?file=/src/CustomTextField.js

Comment: Thanks Olivier. I have modified your work and i tried putting the theme globally. I have a problem with the fieldset, it isn't working. Could you help me with this? Thank you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-custom-textfield-composition-forked-9ojy5?file=/src/theme/overrides/MuiInputLabel.js

Comment: ```
import MuiInputLabel from "./MuiInputLabel";

export default {
  MuiTextField: {
    root: {
      "& fieldset": {
        fontSize: "24px"
      }
    }
  },
  MuiInputLabel
};
```

Comment: There's a space when it has a long label. check this https://pasteboard.co/JEhnV3o.jpg

Answer (score -1):

You should use the Shrink as prop for TextField
Remove `fontSize: "24px"` let it resize by Material-UI
Make sure your TextField as:
`<TextField InputLabelProps={{shrink: true}} .../>`

if you want to customize the size of the label:

```
    fontSize: 30,
    color: "red",
    "&$labelFocused": {
      color: "purple"
    }
  },
  labelFocused: {}
};
function App({ classes }) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        id="standard-with-placeholder"
        label="Your Label"
        InputLabelProps={{
          classes: {
            root: classes.labelRoot,
            focused: classes.labelFocused
          }
```

Comment: I wanted to enlarge the Label of theTextField when its on shrink mode cause its too small thats why is put the `fontSize: '24px'`

Comment: Could you complete your answer? Its missing